# Delete Row if keyword found in column A? not case sensitive

Tags: excel, vba

99% of all answers is about case sensitive value.
What I am looking for is a code to delete the row if one of these keywords found in column A
so regardless if it is capital letter or small letter

keywords: tfg, tfb, Steam, Roast

```
Column A

Roast potatoes 1/2 cut 45gm finished 37 1/2s
Roast pumpkin 75gm finished weight 10s ht
ROCKMELON PEELED AND DICED
Salad Thai Hokkien Noodle 2.5Kg
Tfb coleslaw 1kg bg
Tfb coleslaw 2.5kg
Tfb potato salad 1kg bg
Tfg garden salad gourmet (new) 1.2kg
```

Comment: There are commands in Excel and VBA that compare case sensitive and others that compare case insensitive. So you would need to choose the latter. As an alternative, you can use the UPPER() (or its VBA equivalent) function to change everything in both search string and criteria to upper case and then compare any way that's handy. You really need to post what solution you have so as to enable us to help you improve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way. Work from the bottom upwards because if you go top-down, row deletion will corrupt the iteration.

```
Sub WhyNotAutoFilter()
    dim r as long
    dim offender, offenders
    offenders = split("tfg,tfb,steam,roast", ",")

    for r = Range("A1:A_").rows.count to 1 step -1   'you replace _!
        For each offender in offenders
            'Case not issue since all the same
            if lcase(cells(r,1).value) like "*" & offender & "*" then
                cells(r,1).entireRow.Delete
                'normally would stop checking offenders in case
                'there are several more to check, but not now.
                'But this way if you delete row 8, 7 is still what it
                'was before. Top-Down approach ruins that.
            end if
        next offender
    next r
End Sub
```